# Identifying subjects of these sentences I found in Firefox

Tags: subjects

> ウェブサイトの外観
> 一部のウエブサイトはあなたの設定をもとにカラースキームを適用します。
> これらのサイトでどのカラースキームを使用するか選択してください。

I am not sure about the subject for 使用する. I think it is "websites". Were it written as "使用している" I would understand it as "which you will be using on these websites". Or why not just write it as 使用したい? "Which you want to use"

> 配色
> ウエブサイトのテキスト、背景、リンクを、Firefoxの既定の配色で上書きする。

I think the subject here is 配色. It is a description of what it does. But isn't it also possible to understand it as "you"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of 使用する is implicit "you". で is a particle similar to *on*, *at* or *with*. As a basic rule, something marked with it is never the subject of the sentence.

> これらのサイト**で**どのカラースキームを使用するか選択してください。
> Select which color scheme *you* use **on** such sites.

This setting is related to [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme). Modern websites can detect if a user is using a dark mode and automatically apply a dark theme. But users can turn this feature off and tell websites to always use the light theme or the dark theme.

The subject of the last sentence is also "you". 配色 is not the subject because it is marked with で.

> ウエブサイトのテキスト、背景、リンクを、Firefoxの既定の配色**で**上書きする。
> Overwrite texts, backgrounds and links **with** Firefox's default color scheme

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for clearing this up for me. But I noticed for example in “Anki”, under “新規カード there is a function called “insertion order” in English. But in Japanese it says: “導入する順序”. So “order in which sthが introduces sthを (新規カード)? I do not think the subject is me, as it is the software  that does this for me, either randomly or sequentially. So why not 導入される?

Comment: @美しい孤独 Isn't it 挿入 rather than 導入? If it's 挿入, "you" should make sense as the subject. Either way, I didn't say an implicit subject of a sentence is always "you", did I? It can be anyone or even the software, depending on the context.

Comment: It is 導入. I just checked it. But I am not sure about the accuracy of the Japanese localization of Anki. But it is a fairly popular software, so I considered it to be good Japanese. Anyway I most definitely prefer the English version, as it is much smoother. Btw. to me, correctly reading context in Japanese is very challenging and sometimes I just need to ask, so again thank you very much :)